# Is it safe to put information from an untrusted source as python exception message?

Tags: python, security, code-injection

Is there any way that the following is dangerous? As in, can code get executed if someone prints this exception to `stdout`?

```
def somefunc(val_from_untrusted_source):
    if val_from_untrusted_source == 'something_we_except':
        # do something useful
        pass
    else:
        raise RuntimeException('unknown input: {}'.format(val_from_untrusted_source))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never to that!

Log messages are meant to inform about processing and should be securely delivered to allow to find evidences of what happened in case of problems. Here no control is done so here are some possible problems:

- `str(val_from_untrusted_source)` could itself raise an exception, among which `UnicodeEncodeError` for unicode strings containing non ASCII characters in Python 2, or `UnicodeDecodeError` for byte strings containing non ASCII characters in Python 3. This also includes object specially crafted with an exception raising `__str__` method
- `str(val_from_untrusted_source)` could be a looooong string. It includes long byte or unicode string, but also tiny objects specialy crafted:

  ```
  class DONT:
      def __init__(self, size, pattern):
          self.pattern = pattern
          self.size = size
      def __str__(self):
          return self.pattern * self.size
  ```

  They could cause the log file to exhaust to disk space
- An object can be specially crafted with a never ending `__str__` method, or one that tries to exhaust memory. Just imagine a slight variation of above `DONT`...

---

All that is what could happen in the worse use case where code in uncontrolled. In a more real use scenario, `val_from_untrusted_source` will probably be a string. In that case, it is enough to limit its size and handle `UnicodeError` exception:

```
if val_from_untrusted_source == 'something_we_except':
    # do something useful
    pass
else:
    try:
        txt = str(val_from_untrusted_source)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:                # unicode string on Python 2
        txt = val_from_untrusted_source.encode(error = 'replace')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:                # byte string on Python 3
        txt = val_from_untrusted_source.decode(error = 'replace')
    except Exception:                         # quite weird but once we are there...
        txt = "object non convertible to string"
    if len(text) > 47):     # limit length to 50
        txt = txt[:47] + '...'
    raise RuntimeException('unknown input: {}'.format(txt))
```

Comment: Your last point concerning manually crafted objects can be used for *any* function with parameters, whatever it does with them: we can "hack" ```min(a, b)``` this way. I guess the question was about values which can come from outside the app (like strings).

Comment: @EugenePrimako: You are right, the major risk is for strings. I added specially crafted objects mainly to warn that not controlling string input is bad, and not controlling code (think of an `eval`ing service) is worse.

Comment: Is there any general pattern against including contextual information in exception messages?

Comment: @Thijs: Not really. You asked about the possible dangers and I just tried to be as exhaustive as I could... But see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, nothing *dangerous* can't happen. The most unpleasant consequences:

1. (if Python 2 is assumed) If `val_from_untrusted_source` is not ASCII, `UnicodeEncodeError` will occur when trying to raise `RuntimeException`
2. If `val_from_untrusted_source` contains '\r' and someone writes this exception to log - the beginning of the current log line may be overwrited

Comment: `'\r'` is nothing more than a byte. It only returns to the beginning of the line when displayed to a terminal or printed. But an hexa editor will happily displays what comes before, the `'\r'` itseft (hex value `0x0d`) and what comes after.